# How to do an operation on each file in a directory with a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do you iterate over each file in a directory with a .bat or .cmd file and run an .exe on the files.
So far I've got:

```
    set /p UserInputPath=Set directory files to compress 
    cd /D "path to my compressMDF4video.exe"

    forfiles /p "%UserInputPath%" /c "compressMDF4video.exe"

    PAUSE
```

But I get an error: Can't find specified file for each of the files
What is the problem here?

Comment: Don't use `forfiles.exe` would be my first suggestion, but if you want to use it, open a Command Prompt window, type `forfiles /?` press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the information presented. It should show you how the command works and help you to see that what you've posted above is not correct. I will also add that your question has been asked, and answered, hundreds of times on this site. I would therefore ask that you utilise the excellent search facility at the top of each page. For example `[batch-file] run command each file directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for command.

```
for /R C:\ %%a in (*) do echo %%a
```

change C:\ with your dir, and echo with your executable file.